# CoordinatorLayout + CollapsingToolbarLayout scrolling underneath the status bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have an odd problem with my layouts.  I have a `CoordinatorLayout` with a `CollapsingToolBarLayout` in it.  I have a transparent status bar to better display the image in the top.  Thus I have `fitsSystemWindow` set on this `ImageView`.  The problem I now have is that when the Toolbar is fully collapsed, the top part of the toolbar scrolls behind the system status bar.  Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Here are the screenshots:

[image: Fully open]

[image: Almost closed]

[image: fully collapsed]

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="140dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="90dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <ImageView
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:transitionName="pic"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/missing_album_art"
            android:tint="#AA000000"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:id="@+id/smallicon"/>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:padding="20dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/artist"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textSize="24sp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:id="@+id/date"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
    android:transitionName="bottom">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Also, I tweak the layout parameters a bit when creating the activity:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: If you don't want `Status Bar Color Transparent` then you can change it with `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>`.

Comment: @jaydroider I do want the status bar to remain transparent.  I just don't want the toolbar to scroll behind the status bar

Comment: Take your `Recycler View` inside `Frame Layout` with `Height and Width` to `match_parent` try and check this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to the root of your layout i.e. `CoordinatorLayout`

> Most of the time, your app won’t need to draw under the status bar or the navigation bar, but if you do: you need to make sure interactive elements (like buttons) aren’t hidden underneath them. That’s what the default behavior of the android:fitsSystemWindows=“true” attribute gives you: it sets the padding of the View to ensure the contents don’t overlay the system windows.

Read more on this [here](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec#.edvhoyykm).

Comment: I also had to move the fitsSystemWindows="true" flag from the Collapsingtoolbarlayout to the appbarlayout.  Sadly there is no color underneath the status bar but it now doesn't look so buggy!